# How to figure out the exact package name of a `.so` file, so that it can be installed through `zypper`?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, opensuse

```
anisha@linux-dopx:~/tarBalls/qtFlash/bin> ./flashscript 
./flashscript: error while loading shared libraries: libqtnmedia.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

anisha@linux-dopx:~/tarBalls/qtFlash/bin> cnf libqtnmedia.so.2
libqtnmedia.so.2: command not found
```

Is there a pattern somewhere?
How do YOU install a `.so` file through the package manager?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe with :

```
zypper what-provides libqtnmedia.so.2
```

Comment: That was enlightening, thanks. But the output I received is `No providers of 'libqtnmedia.so.2' found.` does this mean that Suse's repository has NO support for this `.so`?

Comment: Yes ... I've trying on my Fedora and i've the same output. Google isn't very "talkative" either about this library

Comment: :) I realized, `libqtnmedia` is a part of `QtitanMultimedia` component and is already present in its zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I think **zypper wp libqtnmedia.so.2**  will do the trick.

zypper wp searches in packages by filename and displays where it is contained.